# Simple clarification- big $O$ and small $O$ notations in Erdos-Kac theorem proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, probability-theory, proof-explanation

From The Probabilistic Method by Alon and Spencer. Let $\nu(n)$ be the number of primes $p$ dividing $n$ and set \begin{equation}
     X_p=
     \begin{cases}
       1, & \text{if}\ p|x, \\
       0, & \text{otherwise.}
     \end{cases}   \end{equation}

> **Theorem 4.2.2** *Let $\lambda$ be fixed, positive, negative or zero. Then* \begin{equation} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
> > \frac{1}{n}|\{x:1\leq x \leq n, \nu(x) \geq \ln \ln n + \lambda
> > \sqrt{\ln \ln n}\}|= \int_{\infty}^\lambda
> > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2} dt.  \end{equation}
>   **Proof.** Fix a function $s(n)$ with $s(n) \rightarrow \infty$ and $s(n)= o((\ln \ln n)^{1/2})$, e.g. $s(n) = \ln \ln\ln n.$ Set $M =
>  n^{1/s(n)}$. Set $X = \sum X_{p}$, the summation over all primes $p
>  \leq M.$ As no $x \leq n $ can have more than $s(n)$ prime factors
>   greater than $M$ we have $\nu(x) - s(n) \leq X(x) \leq \nu(x) $ so
>   that it suffices to show Theorem 4.2.2 with $\nu$ replaced by $X$. 
>   Let $Y_p$ be independent random variables with Pr$[Y_p = 1] = p^{-1}$,
>   Pr$[Y_p = 0]= 1- p^{-1}$ and set $Y = \sum Y_{p}$, the summation over
>   all primes $p \leq M.$ This Y represents an idealized version of $X$.
>   Set \begin{equation} \mu = E[Y] = \sum_{p \leq M} p^{-1} = \ln \ln n +
>  o((\ln \ln n)^{1/2}) \end{equation} and  \begin{equation} \sigma^{2} =
>  \text{Var}[Y] = \sum_{p \leq M} p^{-1}(1-p^{-1})~\ln \ln n
>  \end{equation} and define the normalized $\tilde{Y} = (Y-\mu)/\sigma$.
>   From the Central Limit Theorem $\tilde{Y}$ approaches the standard
>   normal $N$ and $E[\tilde{Y}^{k}] \rightarrow E[N^{k}]$ for every
>   postive integer $k.$ Set $\tilde{X} = (X- \mu)/\sigma$.  We compare
>   $\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y}$.
>
> **For any distinct primes $p_{1},...,p_{s} \leq M$, \begin{equation}   E[X_{p_{1}}...X_{p_{s}}] - E[Y_{p_{1}}...Y_{p_{s}}] = \frac{\left 
> \lfloor \frac{n}{p_{1}...p_{s}} \right \rceil}{n} - 
>  \frac{1}{p_{1}...p_{s}} = O(n^{-1}). \end{equation}**

**My question**: Why does the difference in expectation come out to be $O(n^{-1})$? I know that informally, we write f (x) = O(g(x)) when there exists a positive
function g such that f does not grow faster than g; but, how does that apply in this case?

> We let $k$ be an arbitrary fixed positive integer and compare
>   $E[\tilde{X}^{k}]$ and $E[\tilde{Y}^{k}]$.
>
> **Expanding, $\tilde{X}^{k}$ is a polynomial in $X$ with coefficients $n^{o(1)}$. Further expanding each $X^{j} = (\sum
>  X_{p})^{j}$ --- always
>    reducing $X_{p}^{a} $ to  $X_{p}$ when $a \geq 2$ --- gives the sum of
>    $O(M^{k}) = n^{o(1)}$ terms of the form $X_{p_{1}}...X_{p_{s}}.$**

**My question**: While I know that little $O$ notation is a strict version of big $O$, I don't understand why would the coefficients turn out to be $n^{o(1)}$?

Thank you very much and apology for the long post. I attach the scanned version of the excerpt [here](http://postimg.org/image/amej9m1ut/)  and [here](http://postimg.org/image/5q1yc7onj/) if you prefer that way.

Comment: My most important suggestion: learn the precise definitions of the notations $f(x) = O(g(x))$ and $f(x) = o(g(x))$. From your description it sounds like you have an intuitive idea of them (which is a good thing as far as it goes), but I'm not convinced you know their definitions well enough to use the notation in proofs.

Comment: For example, can you prove rigorously that $\lfloor t \rfloor = t + O(1)$ for any real number $t$? Can you use that to answer your first question?

Comment: $|\lfloor t \rfloor - t| < 1$ for all $t$, so by definition $\lfloor t \rfloor - t= O(1)$ ? applying to my first question, $|E[X_{p_{1}}...X_{p_{s}}] - E[Y_{p_{1}}...Y_{p_{s}}]| = |\frac{\left 
\lfloor \frac{n}{p_{1}...p_{s}} \right \rceil}{n} - 
 \frac{1}{p_{1}...p_{s}}| < K*n^{-1}$ for sufficiently large constant K, therefore by definition $\frac{\left 
\lfloor \frac{n}{p_{1}...p_{s}} \right \rceil}{n} - 
 \frac{1}{p_{1}...p_{s}} = O(n^{-1})$ ?? @GregMartin

Comment: Oh i got it! $|E[X_{p_{1}}...X_{p_{s}}] - E[Y_{p_{1}}...Y_{p_{s}}]| = |\frac{\left 
\lfloor \frac{n}{p_{1}...p_{s}} \right \rceil}{n} - 
 \frac{1}{p_{1}...p_{s}}| < |\frac{1}{p_{1}...p_{s}}-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{p_{1}...p_{s}}|=\frac{1}{n}$ , therefore by definition $\frac{\left 
\lfloor \frac{n}{p_{1}...p_{s}} \right \rceil}{n} - 
 \frac{1}{p_{1}...p_{s}} = O(n^{-1})$. thank you so much! you're life savior!! :) :) :)i'd really appreciate it if you can also shed some light on the second question :) ) @GregMartin